# SQL(SQL/Oracle) insert value from a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I want to insert (user_id) value from a select statement like below. Can this query will work on both sqlserver and oracle? Kindly advise.

```
insert into b_user (user_id,
                    user_name,
                    user_email,
                    user_address,
                    user_city,
                    user_state,
                    user_country,
                    user_zip)
values (
   select max(user_id) from b_user ,
   david brown,
   david@david.com,
   chicago,
   il,
   usa,
   60007)
```

Comment: That won't work on any dbms that I know - for multiple reasons. Trying to write agnostic SQL is difficult and requires a basic knowledge of at least one dialect. Even if you limit your usage to ANSI SQL (and which version?) not every dbms supports every language feature.

Answer (score 2):

No, that query won't work in either Oracle or SQL Server.  You can do an `insert` based on a `select` statement, however.  Note that you also have to treat strings as strings and enclose them in quotes.

```
insert into b_user (user_id,
                    user_name,
                    user_email,
                    user_address,
                    user_city,
                    user_state,
                    user_country,
                    user_zip)
   select max(user_id) user_id,
          'david brown',
          'david@david.com',
          'chicago',
          'il',
          'usa',
          '60007'
     from b_user
```

Comment: Thank you so much @justin cave. Really appreciated for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

If we insert bracket `()` around the `SELECT` statement, it will work. I tried for SQL Server and it's working for me. Maybe you can try the following query for the Oracle as well.

```sql
insert into b_user (user_id,
                    user_name,
                    user_email,
                    user_address,
                    user_city,
                    user_state,
                    user_country,
                    user_zip)
values (
   (select max(user_id) from b_user),
   'david brown',
   'david@david.com',
   '123 davids street',
   'chicago',
   'il',
   'usa',
   60007
)
```

Comment: You forgot the single quotes around the string literals (like the OP did).

Comment: [SQL Server example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=95c62c91ff7de48d70c9a1fc3a0276b9) and [Oracle example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=95c62c91ff7de48d70c9a1fc3a0276b9).

Comment: @MT0 It works but user_id doesn't get increased. Unfortunately my user_id column is not an identity column. We have to manually increase the value.

Comment: @MT0 i created a fiddle from yours https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=ba954e4d37831a46aea3b3f3b499cc51 https://i.stack.imgur.com/cajtQ.png

Comment: @JSBeginner "It works but user_id doesn't get increased." Of course it doesn't; you're only asking it to get the maximum value rather than getting the maximum value and adding one. However, finding the maximum and incrementing isn't a good way to generate the next value as if it gets run twice at the same time then you may find you get duplicate values. Instead you should be using a sequence and getting the next number from the sequence.

Comment: [Oracle db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=293fa8d6a6b4ecdd7a7e4295697fc796) and [SQL Server db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=91af35165366e0a750acda8459eae8b4) (Or use identity columns)

Comment: @MT0 Also this is an existing table which is unfortunately doesn't set user_id as identity column. Thats why i am trying to set it up the identity column feature via manually.

Comment: @MT0 This is something dynamically generated script which can be used for SQLServer or Oracle db. Right now, i could see the "sequence statement " is difference between oracle and sqlserver. Rest is looks good. How can we have the same sequence statement for both db vendors(sqlserver or oracle)

Comment: @JSBeginner This has strayed from the original question (and it isn't even my answer) and you would do better to ask a new question for the new problem.

Comment: @MT0 Kindly check this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529792/sqlsql-oracle-insert-value-from-a-select-statement-using-sequence